# Execute Subprocess in Background

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a python script which takes an input, formats it into a command which calls another script on the server, and then executes using subprocess:

```
import sys, subprocess

thingy = sys.argv[1]

command = 'usr/local/bin/otherscript.pl {0} &'.format(thingy)
command_list = command.split()
subprocess.call(command_list)
```

I append `&` to the end because `otherscript.pl` takes some time to execute, and I prefer to have run in the background. However, the script still seems to execute without giving me back control to the shell, and I have to wait until execution finishes to get back to my prompt. Is there another way to use `subprocess` to fully run the script in background?

Comment: [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is a lot more flexible than straight out `call` - a bit more overhead but it has the control you're looking for

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`&` is a shell feature.  If you want it to work with `subprocess`, you must specify `shell=True` like:

```
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

This will allow you to run command in background.

Notes:

1. Since `shell=True`, the above uses `command`, not `command_list`.
2. Using `shell=True` enables all of the shell's features.  Don't do this unless `command` including `thingy` comes from sources that you trust.

#### Safer Alternative

This alternative still lets you run the command in background but is safe because it uses the default `shell=False`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command_list)
```

After this statement is executed, the command will run in background.  If you want to be sure that it has completed, run `p.wait()`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to execute it in Background I recommend you to use `nohup` output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("nohup usr/local/bin/otherscript.pl {0} >/dev/null 2>&1 &", shell=True)
```

`>/dev/null 2>&1 &` will not create output and will redirect to background