# Subprocess Module in background?

Tags: python, subprocess

Does the subprocess module in Python execute in the background while you are still able to continue with the program?

For example: If I were to "tail -f *.log" as a subprocess and I read those lines into Python, am I still able to perform other tasks concurrently with the "tail" process happening? Or is that more of a multithread?

Comment: using `subprocess.Popen` runs another process, and you get control of the parent process immediately. Probably what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Subprocess in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577071/execute-subprocess-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_output` will wait until the child process terminates and only then give you it's output.

`subprocess.Popen` does what you want. It will look something like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tail', '-f', '*.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You need the shell=True so that the wildcard in *.log will be interpreted. If not for that, you wouldn't need the shell. Be careful in passing arguments to Popen with shell=True; this can be a security risk if the arguments are user-supplied. It's usually better to find a way that doesn't require the shell. In your case, that would be simple enough - you'd simply have to build the list of log files using python and then pass the list elements as further arguments.

The stdout=subprocess.PIPE is here so that you have a way to read tail's output. You can access it via `proc.stdout` and read from it just like from a regular file.

But reading from it will probably turn out to be somewhat tricky, since you'll have to do it periodically to ensure that the pipe's buffer doesn't fill up and block the tail process. One way to do it is to start a thread that does nothing than read tail's output into a large-enough buffer.