# Run several cmd Windows 10

Tags: python

I want to open several cmd windows with OS Windows 10.
my code:

```
import subprocess

for i in range(0, 3):
    subprocess.<.....what to do......>
```

An ideas, how to implement this in the best way?

Comment: do you actually have commands to execute? Or is this just trying to create several shells to use manually?

Comment: How about the **Safer Alternative** in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577071/execute-subprocess-in-background?answertab=active#tab-top  ?

Comment: At first step how to do this part with subprocess. because with Win 10 a have a problem with this, with linux has not these problems.

Answer (score 2):

using os module is pretty straighforward way on how to accomplish it https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html

```
import os
os.system("start cmd")
```

Comment: It is working fine, but I interested in subprocess aproaches.

Comment: And adding of params is available?

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'])
```

This should open a cmd window.

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'], -- Arguments Go Here --)
```

This one will let you add arguements. I'm not sure if you're using these consoles manually or not.

Comment: open new cmd in current

Comment: how to open not in current?