# Calling a external program stop my script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm a complete beginner with python and i wanted to learn by starting a project.

My first step is to launch an external program and keep the python code running

unfortunately when i execute this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("C:\Program.exe")
print('yes')
```

the program actually run but it doesn't go to next line and execute the print.

My next step would be to check if the program is actually running and i didn't find any thread on this particular issue.

Any clue ?

Comment: It's an expected behavior for `run()`. It waits the external process to terminate, and returns its exitcode: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run . Check [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), particularly an example starting with `with Popen(.....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen("C:\Program.exe")`.

As was done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577744/7132596